# Histogram using a colormap in intervals defined by user

Tags: matplotlib, colors, color-scheme

I would like to replicate the first plot in the next figure:
[image]

I am able to recreate the fist plot, using a single color, since its just an uniform distribution. However, I am not able to create a color palette as the figure, since when using:

`color = plt.cm.viridis(P)   patch.set_facecolor(color)`
it restricts me to the range [0, 1]. Additionally, plt.histogram/sns.hisplot doesn't allow me to give an array of colors created using the intervals in the figure.

How could I reproduce this plot with the given colors?

Comment: This looks like a stacked barchart.

Comment: You aren't showing test data, not even describing how your data look like.  You can use `sns.histpot(..., hue=..., multiple='stack')` to create a stacked histogram.  E.g. with the iris dataset: `sns.histplot(data=iris, x='petal_length',  hue='species', multiple='stack')`